# Coluna fora da condição WHERE do SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne uma coluna com a quantidade de pedidos que o cliente fez dentro do período passado no WHERE e junto uma outra coluna com o total de pedidos que o cliente fez até então. Mais ou menos assim:

```
[CLIENTE][COMPRAS NO PERÍODO][COMPRAS NO TOTAL]
 Marcos           5                 28
 Flávio           7                 35
 Roberta          9                 32
```

Como eu faria isso?

Obrigado!

EDIT

Aqui está o SQL que estou usando para os testes. O que quero na verdade é o campo [Título Total] com a mesma ideia que falei acima:
(Ah, detalhe: não posso alterar a estrutura do BD. Ele já está implantado)

```
SELECT CustosVendaItemPed.CodConta
        ,CustosVendaItemPed.Descricao
        ,OrdensProducao.NumOrdem 'OP'
        ,NotasFiscais.DataEmissao 'Data Emissão'
        ,NotasFiscais.NumNota 'Nota'
        ,OrcHdr.NomeCliente 'Cliente'
        ,NotasFiscais.ValorTotalNota 'Valor NF'
        ,'PercComissao' = CASE WHEN Natureza LIKE 'C' AND OrdensProducao.Cancelado = 0 
                          THEN SUM(Valor/SPreco) END
        ,'Titulo Período' = COUNT(FIN_Titulos.IdTipoDocumento)
        ,'Titulo Total' = ???

FROM OrcHdr 
INNER JOIN OrdensProducao ON OrcHdr.NumOrdem = OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
INNER JOIN CustosVendaItemPed ON OrdensProducao.NumOrdem = CustosVendaItemPed.NumPedido
INNER JOIN ItemNota ON OrdensProducao.NumOrdem = ItemNota.NumOrdem 
INNER JOIN NotasFiscais ON ItemNota.ObjID_Nota = NotasFiscais.ObjID
INNER JOIN FIN_Titulos ON NotasFiscais.ObjID = FIN_Titulos.ObjIDDoctoOrigem

WHERE CustosVendaItemPed.Descricao NOT LIKE 'CIN%' 
AND CustosVendaItemPed.Descricao NOT LIKE 'Centro Integrado%' 
AND CustosVendaItemPed.Descricao NOT LIKE 'não pagar%' 
AND NotasFiscais.Situacao LIKE 'N' 
AND ItemNota.Fatura LIKE 'F' 
AND ItemNota.Devolucao NOT LIKE 'D' 
AND NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao NOT LIKE 'reme%' 
AND NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao NOT LIKE 'doa%' 
AND FIN_Titulos.DebCred LIKE 'C' 
AND FIN_Titulos.Situacao <> 3 
AND DataVencimento >= '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND DataVencimento <= '2012-11-30 00:00:00.000')

GROUP BY 
        CustosVendaItemPed.CodConta
        ,CustosVendaItemPed.Descricao
        ,OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
        ,NotasFiscais.DataEmissao
        ,NotasFiscais.NumNota
        ,OrcHdr.NomeCliente
        ,NotasFiscais.ValorTotalNota
        ,CustosVendaItemPed.Natureza
        ,OrdensProducao.Cancelado
        ,DataVencimento

Order By 
        CustosVendaItemPed.CodConta
        ,CustosVendaItemPed.Descricao
        ,OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
```

Comment: Depende da sua modelagem, apresente sua estrutura pro pessoal e o código que você conseguiu até agora. Mas um caminho seria _sub-query's_...

Comment: Tem como você mostrar a modelagem do banco.
Onde estam as FKS.

Comment: Não resolveria tu colocar uma subconsulta no teu select? seria mais ou menos como propus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outra alternativa seria utilizar `CROSS APPLY` ou `OUTER APPLY`, ambas executam uma função ou consulta sobre o resultado de um *select*, por exemplo:

Considere as tabelas

```
Tabela Cliente
| Id | Nome  |
|  1 | Pedro |
|  2 | João  |

Tabela Compra
| IdCliente | Produto |
|     1     | Arroz   |
|     1     | Feijão  |
```

Para saber quantos produtos cada cliente comprou, você poderia fazer assim:

```
SELECT
    cli.Id,
    cli.Nome,
    prd.Qtde
FROM
    Clientes cli -- select principal
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) Qtde 
                 FROM Compra cmp 
                 WHERE (cmp.IdCliente = cli.Id)) prd -- select secundário
```

O resultado seria:

```
| Id | Nome  | Qtde |
|  1 | Pedro |   2  |
|  2 | João  |   0  |
```

O `CROSS APPLY` e o `OUTER APPLY` são semelhantes ao `INNER JOIN` e ao `LEFT JOIN`, respectivamente, pois o `CROSS` faz com que somente os registros comuns entre o *select* principal e o *select* secundário sejam exibidos, diferente do `OUTER`, que retorna todos os registros do *select* principal e mais os registros do *select* secundário encontrados.

Para esse exemplo acima, você poderia utilizar o `CROSS` ou o `OUTER`, pois sempre vai existir um registro no *select* secundário.

> **Notas:** as tabelas dos exemplos foram simplificadas para facilitar o entendimento e as "nomenclaturas", *select* principal e secundário só serviram para fazer a ligação do exemplo com o texto.

Se quiser saber um pouco mais sobre o `CROSS` e o `JOIN`, você pode dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: e com relação a performance? eu sei que o meu exemplo não é nada recomendado, mas é funcional. normalmente nesses tipos de casos prefiro desnormalizar o banco para ganhar em performance de consulta.

Comment: não cheguei a fazer comparações de desempenho, mais você poderia realizar um teste com ambas as abordagens e comparar, achei interessante postar essa outra opção porque já tive um caso semelhante e o `OUTER APPLY` foi a solução

Comment: Vou tentar achar um exemplo no meu sistema pra ver o desempenho.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente e o retorno foi mais rápido comparado ao uso da Subconsulta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

A solução para seu caso é usar uma subconsulta, ficando da seguinte forma.

```
,'Titulo Total' = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM FIN_Titulos TitulosTotal 
                   WHERE NotasFiscais.ObjID = TitulosTotal.ObjIDDoctoOrigem)
```

Comment: Estou tentando fazer algo assim. Vamos ver...

Comment: pelo que pude entender de sua consulta, seria algo semelhante `,'Titulo Total' = (select count(*) from OrdensProducao OrdensProducao2 where OrcHdr.NumOrdem = OrdensProducao2.NumOrdem)`

Comment: Ótimo! Me ajudou muito Pablo, obrigado!
Tive que fazer algumas modificações, mas a ideia é usar Subconsulta sim.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz minha SELECT assim:

```
SELECT CustosVendaItemPed.CodConta
        ,CustosVendaItemPed.Descricao
        ,OrdensProducao.NumOrdem 'OP'
        ,NotasFiscais.DataEmissao 'Data Emissão'
        ,NotasFiscais.NumNota 'Nota'
        ,OrcHdr.NomeCliente 'Cliente'
        ,NotasFiscais.ValorTotalNota 'Valor NF'
        ,'PercComissao' = CASE WHEN Natureza LIKE 'C' AND OrdensProducao.Cancelado = 0 
                          THEN SUM(Valor/SPreco) END
        ,'Titulo Período' = COUNT(FIN_Titulos.IdTipoDocumento)
        ,'Titulo Total' = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                           FROM FIN_Titulos TitulosTotal 
                           WHERE NotasFiscais.ObjID = TitulosTotal.ObjIDDoctoOrigem)
```

Obrigado!